# "la frase francesa" or "la frase en francés"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

In English, when referring to a sentence written in French, I could say "the French sentence" or "the sentence in French". English is not my first language, but I think those two variants can be used interchangeably. Does the same apply to Spanish, i.e. could I use both "la frase francesa" and "la frase en francés", or is one better/more idiomatic than the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both can be correct.

That said, *en francés* is much better, mainly because when using the adjective form, it could be interpretted either as a phrase either rendered in the French language (*en la lengua francesa*) or as a phrase with its origin in France (*del país francés*) which may or may not be rendered in the French language:

- *la frase española*: maybe in Spanish, maybe a Spanish saying
- *la frase en español*: definitely in Spanish (may or may not be from Spain)
- *la frase de España*: definitely from Spain (may or may not be in Spanish)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe RAE (Royal Academy), francesa as an adjective cannot mean French. Therefore "Literatura francesa de Quebec" would be a contradiction.

This means that according to RAE you should say “la frase en francés”.

Whenever I read “la Wikipedia inglesa” (14,300 times in Google) I agree with RAE, because to me that sentence means “Wikipedia from England”.

Comment: An alternative could also be to use "la Wikipedia anglófona".  Note, however, that the RAE doesn't necessarily encapsulate every single use especially when meaning my be transparent.

The RAE itself published a book titled _La primera versión castellana de Eneida_, where clearly _castellana_ refers to the language, though like _francés_, _español_, or _inglés_, there exists not adjectival definition similar to "perteneciente a la lengua castellana".

Context will rule everything.